# Why does Carroll Oerstadt not think he will stay in jail?

Tags: plot-explanation, deja-vu

In [*Deja Vu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_Vu_(2006_film)) (2006),  the bomber (Carroll Oerstadt) is caught and gets interviewed in his cell.  He seems to think something will happen to get him out of jail, and it won't even reach trial because bigger things are going on.

I presumed this would be dealt with later in the movie. But it wasn't, and he seems to be a lone wolf.

What was he referring to?

Comment: I've always thought that he knew events would "replay" and that he could expect another ending. Like many movies with time-travel or time-loops, characters have sometimes some knowledge from past/futur experiences.